# How to make the underlines the same size in all browsers with css?

Tags: css, underline

When I have the following in css, the underlines under the links in IE and Firefox are "doubled". I have seen that some websites have the same font-family, same font-size, in bold and underlines are not doubled. How can I make the underline only one line and not two (1px vs 2px). A simple css that would work in all browsers (if possible). I know I could use border-bottom to solve the problem but I don't really like the idea.

```
.a_12 {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Thank you for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot control how browsers render their text underlines using CSS. If you really need that level of control, it doesn't hurt to use a bottom border.

Comment: even that may be different between browsers, but is better than the `underline`.

Comment: if your element has any kind of padding, the border "underline" will misbehave...

Answer (score 0):

try to use this property: `border-width: 1px` or play with `border-bottom` property

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `border-bottom` technique suggested in several other posts is to use an `inset` `box-shadow`, like so:

```
box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 inset;
```

Leaving out the `color` parameter defaults to the text color.